# How long does it take for islands to form after an underwater volcanic eruption?

Tags: science-based, internal-consistency, geology, habitability, volcanoes

So, vaguely, I remember from earth science that when submarine volcanoes erupt they eventually form archipelagos. My question actually has several parts;

- Starting with the first eruption to break surface, how long does it take for those islands to <s>form and</s> become habitable? i.e has vegetation, and sources of food, drinkable water.
- *Without the use of modern technology*, is there a way to know that the eruption occurred?

The antagonist in my current WIP is the deity of mountains and volcanoes, she creates these islands so she can have a place to do her scheming and such out of sight of the other deities. The eruption occurs in the middle of the ocean so the water is fairly deep. Saltwater if that makes any difference.

- Is this a quick or slow process, does she have the time to make the islands habitable before getting caught?
- How would the water itself be affected by the eruption? The aquatic animals?

  > I know initially the water will be hot and the fishies will most likely not love that-- but after cooling etc. how does the pH change, mineral content, current, plant life, animal species change?

Comment: Without even googling, I know it's gonna be a number of years with a lot of zeroes behind it. I would imagine at least on the order of tens of thousands, possibly millions or more. Your deity had better be a long-term planner (unless she can speed up the process with her magic)!

Comment: I figured as much, but how long is that really in the eyes of the gods? haha.

Comment: EarthScience.SE would know...

Comment: "How long" certainly depends on how deep the water is.  "How would the water itself be affected by the eruption?"  Maybe... it would get hot.  The aquatic animals probably wouldn't like that, and swim away.

Comment: do you mean how long from when the volcano first forms or how long from a seamount with no land  to an island, the latter only takes days. you may be interested in recently formed islands (as in within the last decade). Hunga Tonga-Hunga Haʻapai, South Pacific and Nishinoshima, Japan

Comment: Depends. From a few days/weeks to a very long (= geological) time. Islands which form in a very short time, e.g., [Graham/Ferdinandea/Julia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graham_Island_(Mediterranean_Sea)) tend to have a short life. Islands which form very slowly tend to live much longer.

Comment: @RonJohn thanks I'll be checking that out now.

Comment: @John not so much the formation of the volcano but how long from the eruption. But I could consider the latter as well, as she could just rise the seamount from the water.  thanks for references as well, in the process of looking those up

Comment: That's what I mean an island is not the process of a single eruption, but hundreds if not more, are you talking about from the first eruption on hte sea floor or the first one to break the surface? Also what do you define as habitable, cool enough to stand on, has vegitation, what.

Comment: Something else to include, how much influence will the deity have on the vegetation and animals? It has to get there from somewhere, and the middle of the ocean isn't going to have many sources of land animals and plants, but if the deity brings seeds and animals over in secret, it could greatly speed the process up.

Comment: This is an interesting first post. Unfortunately, I see three questions here.  This site is set up in a Q&A format for 1 question and its answers for each post.  Multiple questions should be in multiple posts (linked together if you wish).  It shouldn't be hard to edit this post down to your main question.  I just wanted to let you know why I'm voting to put it on hold.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's do some math, using Sherwood's Surtsey example.  We could use the Hawaii example instead, but I'm assuming your deity would prefer to build islands at Surtsey-speed instead of Hawaii's leisurely pace:

It was roughly one day between the start of the Surtsey eruptions, and when the new land broke the surface of the water.  Let's call it a rise of 130m/day.

But!  New land doesn't just rise vertically.  Most undersea eruptions form cinders, with an average angle of repose of 35 degrees.  So let's transform Surtsey's vertical rise into a volume.  We know the height and the angle of repose, let's use that to get the radius of our land-cone:
r = h * tan(x)
where x is 90 degrees minus our angle of repose:
r = 130 * tan(90-35) = 130 * tan(55) = 186m

From there, we can get the volume of volcanic matter that was erupted that day:
volume = pi * r<sup>2</sup> * h / 3 = 4709750 m<sup>3</sup> / day

Now let's assume the source of your islands erupt at the same rate.  However, the depth they need to rise from is a *little* more than Surtsey.  The abyssal plain lies at a depth of 3000-6000m, so let's go with a depth of 4500m.  Your island's required time is:

r = 4500 * tan(55) = 6427m
v = pi * 6427<sup>2</sup> * 4500 / 3 = 194651489600 m<sup>3</sup>
days = v / rate = 194651489600 / 4709750 = 41329 days = 113 years

So, you could get your islands in a little over a century, provided you keep the volcanic activity at a relatively frenetic pace the entire time.

As for when life arrives, I'd give it less than a year.  Life is pretty impressive when it comes to colonizing new land.

Answer (score 13):

Google Surtsey.

http://www.surtsey.is/pp_ens/gen_3.htm

This was an undersea volcano that formed off the coast of iceland.  National Geographic had a series of articles on it.

The water was shallow(130 m), so the island didn't have to make a huge thickness of land to get above the surface.

Before breaking the surface, there was a lot of bubbles, floating pumice, ash clouds, but the interval from the start of the eruption to breaking surface was days.

First plants were there within a year.  At this point the island is covered in green.  Nearest land is 18 km away.

Comment: this was very helpful thank you. Do you think this process was so quick because the water was shallow? How would it be different in the middle of the sea?

Comment: *Building* the island is quick.  *Keeping* the island is hard -- barring further eruptions, Surtsey has a remaining life expectancy of a century or so before it erodes completely.

Comment: Build time should go up with roughly the cube of the water depth.  The abyssal plain is about 4000 meters, 30 times as deep.  Assuming the erruption didn't stop it would take roughly 30^3 or 27,000 times as long for it to break the surface.

Answer (score 10):

## **Hawaii, as a case study: Millions of years**

From https://dhrititimelineofplatetectonics.weebly.com/formation-of-hawaii.html :

> This is how the islands first became to form **40 million years ago**
> even though some were able to **start developing 70 million years**
> ago.
>
> ...
>
> The oldest island of Hawaii is Kauai which formed 5.1
> million years ago, then Niihau which formed 4.9 million years ago,
> then Oahu, Hawaii's third largest island formed 3 and a half million
> years ago, followed by Molokai which was formed 1 and a half million
> years, then Maui, Hawaii's second largest island formed a million
> years ago and lastly The Big Island of Hawaii which formed half a
> million years ago and is the youngest of the Hawaiian chain.  **Another
> volcano named Lo'ihi is being created currently and is expected to
> emerge from the seas in 10,000 to 100,000 years time as it is still
> 1000m below the ocean's surface** and become an island.

From this quote, we can see that from beginning (eruptions on the sea floor beginning) all the way to having an island, it takes millions of years. Individual islands can form concurrently, however, and emerge next to each other within the space of tens or hundreds of thousands of years.

Comment: Lots of useful information, but I feel that the question is about a duration of a specific step in the process (volcano to an island with vegetation), so the age of a younger parts of Big Island (100,000-300,000 years) should be more to the point.

Answer (score 2):

Rangitoto Island in New Zealand is an example of forming and being covered in vegetation in 600 years. From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rangitoto_Island),

> Rangitoto was formed by a series of eruptions commencing at least 6000 years ago.[7] The most recent eruptions occurred between 550 and 600 years ago in two episodes, 10 to 50 years apart, and are thought to have lasted for several years during the later shield-forming episode. The first recent episode erupted most of the volcanic ash that mantles neighbouring Motutapu Island, and produced the lower, northern scoria cone. The second episode built most of Rangitoto